# RAZOR how to get the value from a list of Radio Buttons

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am new to RAZOR and am very interested in this new tech.

Now I have 2 RasdioButtons : Monthly Member  and Yearly Member

I want to get the selected value from them.

Anyone can shed some light on it?

I highly appreciate if you can even provide me a small demo code.

I am looking forward to your replies.

Here is the RAZOR code.

```
@{
    var name = Request["name"];
    var dobDay = Request["dobDT"];
    var dobMonth = Request["dobMT"];
    var dobYear = Request["dobYR"];
    var gender = Request["gender"];
    var address = Request["address"];
    var city = Request["city"];
    var state = Request["state"];
    var country = Request["country"];

    @*Login details*@
    var email = Request["email"];
    var email2 = Request["email-2"];
    var pwd = Request["pass"];
    var pwd1 = Request["pass-2"];

    @*Membership Plan*@

    bool monthlyPlan = false;

    if(Request[""])

}
```

Here is the html code

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40" align="center">
                                        <input type="radio" name="memType" value="m" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="200">
                                        <b>Monthly</b> ( $9.95 per month )
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="40" align="center">
                                        <input type="radio" name="memType" value="y" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <b>Yearly</b> ( $95.50 per year )
                                    </td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: Get the selected value ...how?  On the server after postback?  In the client using Javascript?  Would help to post some code.

Comment: @dbaseman hi, thx for reminding :) updated

Comment: On a completely separate note and as part of my campaign to eliminate unnecessary table based layout, please consider alternate CSS based layouts e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/S6cXx/

Comment: @JonP thx, any related suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request object uses the "name" attribute of the html form element. This is the same for pretty much all web technologies be it PHP, classic ASP, ASP.net WebForms, ASP.net MVC etc.

In your case `Request["memType"]` should return the value of the selected radio button.

In the case of CheckBoxes or Multiple Select lists a comma delimited string of selected values will be returned.

Comment: @{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Contact";
    
    
}

<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Male", true) Male
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Female", false) Female
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    @Html.Label(Request["Gender"] == null ? "No Selection" : Request["Gender"])
</div>   but it shows No Selection. And do you know how to trigger an event in RAZOR?

Comment: Is "No Selection" appearing after the form has been submitted? It would appear you are setting Male to true by default. On initial page load, i.e. before the form has been submitted, the Request collection for your form elements will be empty until the form is submitted.

Comment: thx for your reply. I have found the solution which is to add a runat attribute. And sadly, they closed my question....